# gentelella - template usage

Tags: spring-boot, gentelella

I plan to use this template on my website for my spring boot web application:
https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella

I have downloaded it and plan to just customized the pages to suit my needs.  However, upon downloading it has a lot of folders one of which is vendors which contains a lot of js libraries amounting to  87.1 MB.  I'm certain I won't be needing everything, my website will only contain a few CRUD pages and that would be it.

How should I use this template? Isn't there a simple example page that I can use and then just add the stuffs that I need one-by-one? instead of using all these files and deleting the ones that I won't be needing (I don't even know which to delete)?

Sorry if this is a noob question. But I hope I make sense.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can check the `css` and `js` files the pages you want to use is using. For e.g. check the `index.html` file and look for the css and js scripts it is referring to. You should create a template structure using any of View tech (Thymeleaf, Tiles, FreeMarker, JSP, etc) after that you can easily add new pages. You can refer this [Project](https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-tiles-sample-app), its using Spring MVC (not Boot) and [AdminLTE](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) using Apache Tiles.

Comment: thank you, I have managed to do this as per your first advise: look at the page that I need, and check the js and css that is referenced and only copy those.

Comment: I started Springboot AdmniLTE using Thymeleaf project, have a look if insterested -  [springboot-adminlte-thymeleaf](https://github.com/RawSanj/springboot-adminlte-thymeleaf).